# Do we have any free inspect tool for java swing application?

Tags: automated-testing

I have one java swing application. I need to automate that application. At first I need to inspect the element from that application. Do we have any free inspect tool for java swing application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/elbosso/swinginspector ?

> a tool to inspect Java Swing GUIs like it is done in browsers with
>   HTML pages

Comment: My application build by jdk1.7 so I cant use this :(

Comment: You should add maximum of relevant details to your question so that people here would not waste time to suggest solutions which do not work for you.